# Terminal command-line debug of iOS Simulator apps?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, debugging, lldb

Is it possible to use GDB or LLDB from the Terminal command-line under Mac OS X to debug apps running on the iOS Simulator?  (e.g. not from within Xcode's GUI or console, but using an external command-line or process).  If so, how?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You'll need to have the app already in the simulator's Springboard; you can't launch the app in the simulator from Xcode and then expect to be able to have a command line instance of gdb attach to it.

So:

1. Run the iOS Simulator, having already gotten your app into it.
2. In a terminal window:

```
    % gdb
    ...
    (gdb) attach --waitfor 'Name Of Your App'
```

1. Launch your app from the simulator Springboard.
2. gdb should attach to the process *before* `main()` is executed. So you can set some breakpoints, or whatever. Then:

```
    (gdb) continue
```

The procedure for `lldb` is similar:

```
    % lldb
    (lldb) process attach -n 'Name Of Your App' --waitfor
    <launch your app in the simulator>
    (lldb) continue
```

I am not sure why you'd want or need to do this, but as an old command line gdb (and dbx) guy, I can appreciate it. :-)

Comment: So nifty. Hat off to you, sir!

Comment: Use `xcrun simctl` commands to install the app on the simulator, then launch it.

Comment: To answer the question of why you might want to do this: in my case it's to investigate iOS CI issues, replicating the console-driven CI process locally and stopping the app at particular points of interest.