# use lldb for iphone project in mac without using xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

I an trying to find out how to debug iphone program without using xcode by [reading here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/gdb_to_lldb_transition_guide/document/lldb-terminal-workflow-tutorial.html) but I cannot get it to work

I managed to change my Xcode setting (Xcode 10) so that the .app file that gets created after build is now inside a folder within my project folder. This makes it easier to get the path to the .app file for lldb, and I can load the app file in lldb using something like

```
$ lldb /Projects/Sketch/build/Debug/Sketch.app
```

but I am not sure what to do from here onwards. I tried `process launch` and `run`, but they don't seem to start the .app file in debug mode like Xcode does. What should I do to start debugging iphone project outside Xcode?

The things I specifically want to do:

- put breakpoints at particular lines of the .m files (in the same way I would click on the line number in a running iphone program in Xcode to put a breakpoint there)
- while at a debug point, display values in arrays using matplotlib (this is the main reason I am trying to run lldb outside of Xcode, as it looks like matplotlib doesn't work in the lldb console in Xcode)
- single step, step over and step out in the C code

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/10112466/5329717 ? And I'd start with verifying if matplotlib would work with raw lldb on some simple MaOS "helloWorld" in C as it will be much easier to setup.

Comment: @Kamil haden't seen that thanks for the link. And if I only start lldb on terminal (not attaching to anything) then matplotlib definitely works, so I guess it should work while debugging a program as well. By reading around questions on the site I have got the idea that matplotlib doesn't work if lldb is being used from within the xcode console, but should work otherwise

Comment: perhaps capturing `stdout` and / or `stderr` output from the `Simulator` outside of `XCode` (but while still using it) would suffice for your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165641/how-can-i-get-the-console-logs-from-the-ios-simulator

Comment: @Kamil I'll be working on an iphone not the simulator, but may be those posts will give some clue on how to do it